# share a view among multiple viewcontrollers in a tab based application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tab based application, in which I want to show a view on all the tabs.

This `UIView` which I wish to share among several tab's view controllers contains a toggle button and come other buttons majorly.

I have a `UITabBarController`, whose view controllers need to share a `UIView`, display this `UIView` in every view controllers of the `UITabBarController`.

How can I achieve this? Any tutorials etc. are also welcome

Comment: Elaborate more details.

Answer (score -1):

Just put this view as a subview in all viewcontrollers  in your app.Then u can write your own init like this

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame parentController:(UIViewController)controller;
```

and specify logic inside your view depending what viewcontroller created the view.

Comment: I'm using a tab bar controller, hence instantiation of the child view controller is not in my hand. Please let me know if I can ovverride this constraint.

Comment: Although you are using tabbar controller, this fact doesn't restrict you to create UIViewController subclasses, and add them to each tab.